# How varied should a strength training workout be?

Tags: muscle, muscle-gain, glutes, thigh

I want to do strength training so that I can increase the size of my glutes and thighs and tone my waist. I normally do a workout with about 12 exercises (4 exercises per body section) with a minute of working out and a minute of rest for each exercise.

### How many different exercises should I do for each part of my body during a workout?

For example, to develop my thighs, should I do **squats, plié squats, alternating lunges and the plank** or just **squats and plié squats** or even just **squats**?

### Should I do a different workout every day?

For example, should I do a completely different workout every day, do a slightly different workout every day, do the same workout every day or alternate between workouts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everyone is different.

There is no recipe only guidelines and common sense. Then it's up to you to adapt to your feelings and evolution. Or at least it should be like that.

Variety is good because most of the time a variation will work primary movers and stabilizers differently. You will make yourself more balance and less injury prone.

Consistency is good also because then you can track your progress quantitatively and this gives you confidence in methodology as well as improving your morale and your desire to train.

So, start working. See how it goes (recovery, mood to train, possible pain) and adapt as necessary (volume, loads, type of exercise).

With one exercise I can make you work very differently already. Concentric focused, eccentric focused, isometric. Slow, fast, many light repetitions, few heavy repetitions. Imagine all the combinations with all the exercises and the way you structure your sessions.

Keep track of your progress, mood to train, potential pain and injuries and adapt.